# array elements does not match same assigned elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

I wrote a function where I am looping through an array(which contains a number of array elements itself).

e.g.

```
theMainAr:[ [ 5 ],[ 5, 3 ],[ 5, 3, 9 ],[ 5, 3, 9, 4 ],[ 3 ],[ 3, 9 ],[ 3, 9, 4 ],[ 9 ],[ 9, 4 ],[ 4 ] ]
```

The main array I got the above array from is :

```
weights: [5,3,9,4]
```

I want to get a combination from these above arrays like this:

```
sameLenAr:[[5,9],[5,4],[5,3,4],[3,4]]
```

But Everytime I get an output like this: `[[5,4],[5,4],[5,3,4],[3,4]]`
The first element is not [5,9]
Why?

```js
let theMainAr = [ [ 5 ],[ 5, 3 ],[ 5, 3, 9 ],[ 5, 3, 9, 4 ],[ 3 ],[ 3, 9 ],[ 3, 9, 4 ],[ 9 ],[ 9, 4 ],[ 4 ] ]
let weights = [5,3,9,4], lenOfWeights = weights.length;
let sameLenAr = []
let inc = 0
for (let i = 1; i < theMainAr.length - 3; i++) {
  let curLen = theMainAr[i].length
  if (curLen > 1) {
    let curAr = theMainAr[i]
    let curArLen = curAr.length
    let indexOfEle = weights.indexOf(curAr[curLen - 1])
    for (let m = indexOfEle + 1; m < lenOfWeights; m++) {
      //   console.log(a)
      curAr[curArLen - 1] = weights[m]
      console.log(curAr)
      sameLenAr[inc] = curAr
      inc++
    }
  }
}

console.log(sameLenAr)
```

Comment: This variable is not defined ```lenOfWets``` and what is your expected result?

Comment: I made you a snippet. I had to add lenOfWeights

Comment: @overflow in the first `for` loop it's `let i = 1;` which means the starting point is at the second position of the array.  It should be `i=0`  if you want to start in the first position of the array.

Comment: @mplungjan I have not posted the entire code. I created lenOfWets before. This is not an error. My question was about the output of sameLenAr

Comment: @zer00ne in the first for loop i=1 because I want to get only those array elements which contain more than one element in it. When I console.log(curAr) it the same loop it shows [5,4] but when I am pushing it or assigning it the same curAr why the sameLenAr[0] contains [5,6]? this is my question?

Comment: We like [mcve] which is why I "fixed" your question with a proper snippet

Comment: Thank you everyone. I have solved it. It was causing the error because I was mutating the curAr. So I did this:
`    let sameLenAr = []
for (let i = 0; i < theMainAr.length - 3; i++) {
  let curLen = theMainAr[i].length
  if (curLen > 1) {
    let curAr = theMainAr[i]
    let indexOfEle = weights.indexOf(curAr[curLen - 1])
    
    for (let m = indexOfEle + 1; m < lenOfWets; ++m) {
         let temSameLenAr = [...curAr]
         temSameLenAr[temSameLenAr.length-1] = weights[m]
        sameLenAr.push(temSameLenAr)  
    }
  }
}`